# Problemas con getline C++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Estoy obteniendo este mensaje de error cuando quiero utilizar getline() en mi código:

no instance of overloaded function "getline" matches the argument list -- argument types are:(std::string, std::string, std::string, std::string, std::string)

Lo que quiero conseguir es almacenar los datos de una persona en un lista lineal simple.

```
void ListaSimpleConMenu::datosDeLista(string)
{
    string carnet, nombreComp, edad, telefono, correo;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Ingrese los datos de la persona en el siguiente orden:" << endl; 
    cout << "Carnet, primer nombre y primer apellido, edad, numero de telefono y correo electronico." << endl << endl;
    getline(carnet, nombreComp, edad, telefono, correo);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Mira la firma de la función [getline](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/)

`istream& getline (istream& is, string& str, char delim);`

`istream& getline (istream& is, string& str);`

La función espera que le indiques el `stream` de donde cogerá los caracteres, el `string` al que irán y opcionalmente un delimitador que le indique dónde dejará de leer del `stream` de entrada.

Aclarado esto, y si por ejemplo quieres introducir los cinco datos separados por un espacio, podrías hacer esto:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string carnet, nombreComp,edad,telefono,correo;

    cout << "Ingrese los datos de la persona en el siguiente orden:" << endl;
    cout << "Carnet, primer nombre y primer apellido, edad, numero de telefono y correo electronico." << endl << endl;
    getline(std::cin,carnet,' ');
    getline(std::cin,nombreComp, ' ');
    getline(std::cin,edad,' ');
    getline(std::cin,telefono,' ');
    getline(std::cin,correo);

    cout<<"carnet: "<<carnet<<endl;
    cout<<"nombre compañia: "<<nombreComp<<endl;
    cout<<"edad: "<<edad<<endl;
    cout<<"telefono: "<<telefono<<endl;
    cout<<"correo: "<<correo<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Ejemplo de entrada:
Pepe MiEmpresa 99 555123456 pepeAtmiempresa.com

Answer (score 1):

Lo normal, salvo excepciones, es que cada dato de los que indicas no tenga espacios en blanco. Para esta tarea es preferible usar `cin` directamente.

Así, si no se espera que ningún campo tenga espacios en blanco podrías dejar el código así:

```
std::cin >> carnet >> nombreComp >> edad >> telefono >> correo;
```

En cambio, si asumimos que `nombreComp` sí pudiese tener espacios:

```
std::cin >> carnet;
std::getline(std::cin, nombreComp);
std::cin >> edad >> telefono >> correo;
```